# Lookup table with columns in the same joined table

Tags: sql-server

In a Microsoft SQL Server Database I have a lookup table that has the following structure:

```
Assistants: 
EmployeeId, AssistantId
```

Those two IDs are in a second table:

```
Employees:
Id, FirstName, LastName
```

I would like to join the two tables and list each Employee and there assistants, it could be more than one. I have tried the following which I thought would work:

```
select * from Assistants
join Employees
on Assistants.EmployeeId = Employees.Id AND Assistants.AssistantId = Employees.Id
```

However it returns nothing, any ideas how I can achieve a listing of each employee and there assistants?

Comment: Why the second part of your join condition ?? `AND Assistants.AssistantId = Employees.Id` would match the **internal ID** of `Assistants` to the `Employee.Id` - I **highly** doubt this will be the case! I bet you just need `on Assistants.EmployeeId = Employees.Id` and that's it ....

Comment: Show us some sample data and expected results, as formatted text, or to make it easier to answer as DDL/DML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the employee table twice - once to get the employee and once to get the assistant.

I'm assuming not all employees have assistants, so you should probably use left joins:

```
SELECT * -- You really should specify the columns names here
FROM Employees As Emp
LEFT JOIN Assistants
    ON Emp.Id = Assistants.EmployeeId 
LEFT JOIN Employees As Assist -- You should probably find a better name for this alias...
    ON Assistants.AssistantId = Assist.Id
```

That will give you a list of all employees and their assistants.
If, however, you can have multiple level of assistants (i.e. the CTO have an assistant CTO and they have an assistant themselves), you will need a recursive cte.

Comment: Thank you I hadn't considered this approach! Yes the columns are a contrived example of the complex data set.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head. Something like this.

```
Select E.ID, E.FirstName, E.LastName, TBLA.FirstName, TBLA.LastName
FROM Employees E
LEFT JOIN (
    Select E.FirstName, E.LastName, A.AssistantId
    from Assistants A 
    INNER JOIN Employees on A.AssistantId = Employees.ID
) TBLA ON TBLA.AssistantId = E.ID
where TBLA.AssistantId is NOT null
```